# Jsonp (global.asax) , WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp

Tags: .net, jsonp

I am trying to instantiate the JsonpMediaTypeFormatter and am not sure what is required for the first parameter in the "new" construct.  I could not find any examples of this on the web.  Many thanks.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp;
namespace IAUWApi
{
    public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            // Add these two lines to initialize Routes and Filters:
            IAUWApi.App_start.WebAPIConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            IAUWApi.App_start.FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter("","callback"));
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably user has solved it long ago, but for reference, here it is, this should do it:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
```